# formset radio value is a php function and is displaying its output in formset are and not in $_POST

Tags: php, forms, mysqli, radio-button, formset

I am coding a database to return a file path which I turn into a gif. On my formset my radio value is displaying in line with its name which I dont want. Iam very new to coding and any input is greatly appreciated.

```
?php
//function in question
 function breakfastq($db_conn){
      $query = "SELECT loc FROM breakfast";
      $result = mysqli_query($db_conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ( $row =  mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    echo '<img src="'.$row['loc'].'" alt="animated breakfast recipe">';
        }
      }
        else {
                  echo "you failed, again!";
        }
      }?>
<fieldset>
   <legend>Please select a meal category</legend>
   <label for="breakfast">Breakfast</label>
   <input type="radio" value="<?php breakfastq($db_conn);?>" name="meal"/>
</fieldset>
<?php echo $_POST['meal'] ?>
```

Comment: your logic is wrong, you can't print image in radio value, radio value is what you get as `$_POST['meal']` if you wrap your input in a Post type form

Comment: I am not sure i follow what you are saying.